# Can not close a java-based web service created in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, executable-jar

I created a REST service Spring Boot Application using Spring Tool Suite. In the STS IDE, I selected "Run As" > "Maven Install". This produced an executable jar. I double clicked the executable jar and I can access my web service by browsing to localhost:8080 in my browser.

The problem is I can't find the darn application on my Task Manager in order to close it! How do I locate and close this application?

Comment: try closing javaw.exe

Comment: Yay! Thank you. I was worried about closing javaw, as I wasn't sure about the broader impacts. But that worked. Many thanks for helping me with such a stupid issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try closing `javaw.exe` which is responsible for java processes.

Comment: Thanks again. I closed the javaw process from Windows Task Manager and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Using STS I'd run the app using *Run As > Spring Boot Application* which gives you full control over the process from STS.
2. I'd go for a `mvn install` or *Run As > Maven Install* cause this will install the application into your local Maven repository which you might not want. A simple `mvn package`or *Run As > Maven build...* and using a *package* as a goal over there will only put you the jar file in the target folder.

Additional note: if you prefer to work on the command line you can also start your app using `mvn spring-boot:run`.